# How to change Bootstrap modal content depending on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I need to be able to change the content inside a modal depending on the button that is clicked.

For instance, if button one is clicked it will only show the `div` with `class` 'one' and the others will remain hidden.

```js
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('toggle')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">one</button>

<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">two</button>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->


<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">three</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="one">Button one content</div>
        <div class="two">Button two content</div>
        <div class="one">Button three content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is described in the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example below. The logic: Whenever you click a button, hide all the content first, then you show the specific content based on the button you clicked.

Ref.: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-related-target

```js
$(".btn").click(function () {
  $(".parent").children().each(function () {
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $(`div.${$(this).attr("id")}`).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>

<!-- jQuery library -->

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button
  id="one"
  type="button"
  class="btn"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
>
  one
</button>

<button
id="two"
  type="button"
  class="btn"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
>
  two
</button>

<button
id="three"
  type="button"
  class="btn"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#exampleModalCenter"
>
  three
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="exampleModalCenter"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="one">Button one content</div>
          <div class="two">Button two content</div>
          <div class="three">Button three content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this tutorial :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-related-target

Simply add a data attribute to your button :

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourModal" data-name="one">Open modal for One</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourModal" data-name="two">Open modal for Two</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#yourModal" data-name="three">Open modal for Three</button>
```

And when the event occur, you can recover the attribute of the button and adapt the behavior according to it :

```js
$('#yourModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('name'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

  // Here, you can change the behavior according to the button clicked :
  switch(recipient) {
    case 'one':
      $('.one').show();
      break;
    case 'two':
      $('.two').show();
       break;
    // etc...
  }
});
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the modal's [show.bs.modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#events) event, check the value of the `relatedTarget` property of the event and then show/hide internal divs based on that target value

Answer (score 0):

```js
 

   $(document).on("click",".modal-open",function(){
        var button_val = $(this).attr("data-val");

        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
        $(".conditional-div").hide();
        $("#exampleModalCenter ."+button_val).show();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn modal-open" data-val="one" >one</button>
<button type="button" class="btn modal-open" data-val="two" >two</button>
<button type="button" class="btn modal-open" data-val="three" >three</button>

   
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->


<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="one conditional-div">Button one content</div>
        <div class="two conditional-div">Button two content</div>
        <div class="three conditional-div">Button three content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```js
$('button.btn-open-modal').on('click', function(){
    let targetClass = $(this).attr("target-class");
    $("#exampleModalCenter div.modal-body > div").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass(targetClass)){
            $(this).show();
        }else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('toggle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->


<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-open-modal" target-class="one">one</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-open-modal" target-class="two">two</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-open-modal" target-class="three">three</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="one">Button one content</div>
        <div class="two">Button two content</div>
        <div class="three">Button three content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```